# Lua - Idea on lua for split a word into vowels and consonants

Tags: split, lua

I'm looking for a way in lua to make a simple program to split a word in vowels and consonants, any idea?

Comment: any own ideas? this is not a thinking service. hint: you can compare characters

Comment: I have thought about 2  nested cycle to check if a char is a consonant or vowels, and add it to the relative array/string but I would like to know if there is a smarter way.

Comment: So cycling on the word characters and compare each one with each character of two string, one with only vowels and one with only consonants.

Comment: will you have any numbers or other characters in your words?

Comment: No, they will be name, but there could be '  apostrophe. it could be not a problem, if it doesn't match we are just ignoring it

Comment: vowels `print(s:gsub("[^eyuioaj]",""))`

Comment: That's the way we were doing it in java, thanks for the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as an example, for vowels, you can select them using a pattern:

```
local s = "qaaaawertyuieeertyrtyyopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
print(s:gsub("[^eyuioaj]",""))
```

output:

```
aaaaeyuieeeyyyoaj
```

consonants similarly